# What decides with file type (extension) is used for export to excel from ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, export-to-excel, reportviewer

I'm using Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms 10.0.40219.1 in a WinForm application to let the users get the option to save the content of a data table to an excel file.

I have now noticed that when running different deployed versions of the application I in one case get the option to save as .xls file and in another case get the option to save as a .xlsx file.

Does anyone know what decides with version of excel file (extension) that is used?

The application is deployed as a click once installation. Both versions is deployed on the same application server. I'm running both versions from the same computer.

/Robert.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your config file on the report server.

It should usually be in the following directory (depending on version)

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting
> Services\ReportServer

ALWAYS BACKUP YOUR **rsreportserver.config** FILE BEFORE YOU MAKE ANY CHANGES!

Look for the following in the config file - if there isn't one, add it. You can add a tag at the end of other extensions to set the visibility

```
> <Extension Name="EXCELOPENXML"
> Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering"/>
```

You can see below, one for Word that saves as .doc (set to be hidden) and another for wordopenxml that does .docx

```
<Extension Name="WORDOPENXML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordOpenXmlRenderer.WordOpenXmlDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering"/>             <Extension Name="WORD" 


Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering" Visible="false"/>
```

You may need to restart services for this to take effect.

If the service does not start, you have stuffed up the config file!

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for our answer Harry.

I do not think it has anything to do with the rsreportserver.config file on the server. Changing in that file does apply changes to the export-button when running a report on the server.

In my case I am using the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms object in my application. When using reportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions(), I only get EXCEL as one out of three visible options. I do not get any ExcelOpenXML option. I think that it has something to do with that. But why I do not get the option ExcelOpenXML I do not know.

/Robert.

Comment: @RobertWalter, You are using a old version of the ReportViewer control. Perhaps try using the [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms/#supportedframeworks-body-tab).